# Transformation mapping between input and output files using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I have two files with me, an input file and an output file. The input file goes through a transformation logic and produces the output file. The issue here is that, I am not aware of the transformation logic between the input and output file.
The input file contains 10 fields and output file contains 7 fields. These 10 fields are transformed into 7 fields using a transformation logic.

Is there way using some machine learning algorithm, to build a model that automatically deduce the relationship between input and output and will be able to predict the output based on the data in the input file?

Comment: You might want to write some more about the data structure you have, especially, which datatypes the fields have. So fas I can tell you, yes this is possible but without more information it could be either rather "simple" or difficult

Comment: Values in both the files are of mixed type, both categorical and continuous and are space separated.

Comment: To answer your question in short: yes. You can find my longer answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think I have something, that might help you solve your issue:
You have various inputs with different datatypes. Also you have different outputs with different datatypes. Lets have this dataset as example when working with tensorflow and keras:

```
x_categorical=[1,2,3,4,5]
x_categorical_2=np.random.choice(x_categorical, len(x_categorical))
x_continuus=np.random.random_sample(len(x_categorical))

y_categorical = [0,2,3,4,5]
y_continuus = np.random.random_sample(len(x_categorical))
```

Create the tf.data.Datasets and zip the x and y values together, so it fits the model input:

```
ds_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_categorical)
ds_x1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_categorical_2)
ds_x2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_continuus)

dataset_x = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_x,ds_x1,ds_x2))

ds_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_categorical)
ds_y1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_continuus)

dataset_y = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_y,ds_y1))

dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_x, dataset_y))
```

Build an example model, which concatenates the inputs, has one layer which contains the "logic" for the data combination and two more layers, that have a logic for each output:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers as layer
layer_input_categorical = layer.Input(shape=(1),name="x_categorical", dtype=tf.float32)
layer_input_categorical_2 = layer.Input(shape=(1),name="x_categorical_2", dtype=tf.float32)
layer_input_continuus = layer.Input(shape=(1),name="x_continuus", dtype=tf.float32)

concat_layer = layer.Concatenate()([layer_input_categorical,layer_input_categorical_2, layer_input_continuus])

dense_layer = layer.Dense(100)(concat_layer)

dense_layer_out_cat = layer.Dense(50)(dense_layer)

dense_layer_out_con = layer.Dense(50)(dense_layer)

output_categorical = layer.Dense(5, activation="softmax")(dense_layer_out_cat)

output_continuus = layer.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(dense_layer_out_con)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[layer_input_categorical, layer_input_categorical_2, layer_input_continuus], \
                       outputs=[output_categorical, output_continuus])

model.compile(optimizer="Nadam", loss=["mse","sparse_categorical_crossentropy"])
```

Please note the usage of two loss functions (mse for regression and sparse_categorical_crossentropy for classification.

Also note, that the two output layers have different activation functions, softmax for classification (for each class, you get the probability) and one sigmoid for regression.

At the end, just start the training with:

```
model.fit(dataset_train.batch(1), epochs=20)
```

For sure this is not the best way of doing it, but it proves, that is is possible.